# How do I disable the Russian keyboard layout in software?

Tags: macos, settings, input-source

I enabled Russian input source, and am having problem disabling it.

How do I disable it?

Comment: With input source, do you mean the keyboard layout?

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by Russian input source? This?  http://www.topnews.in/files/Vodka_1.jpg :)

Comment: @patrix Input source is a generic term used for keyboard layouts and other input methods (like Chinese trackpad handwriting).

Answer (score 6):

The "hard" way:

[image: Uncheck Russian Input Sources]

The "easy" way:
[image: Uncheck Russian Input Sources!]