# typing a backtick on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard, internationalization

I have had a hunt around the net for this, but cannot find an answer - how do I type a backtick on Mac OSX Snow Leopard? I have a Macbook from late-2010.

The backtick character is one I use on a regular basis on StackExchange.

Comment: Which keyboard layout do you use? On my keyboard, it is next to Shift.

Comment: You mean ` ? What keyboard layout do you have?

Comment: @Radoo Yes, I mean `. Thanks it is indeed next to the [SHIFT] key.

Comment: @guwac I'm not sure why I didn't see that, but thank you. Can you submit an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume you don't have the English keyboard layout. You need to set up the U.S. Input Source, similar to what is described here (actually it's the other way around, you want to Check U.S.): [How do I disable the Russian keyboard layout in software?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48587/how-do-i-disable-the-russian-keyboard-layout-in-software/48593#48593)

Then select that Layout and press the key right to left Shift.

Comment: The UK keyboard has ` next to shift - what is the issue you raise?

Comment: On other countries layouts, instead of ` you have a letter, for a specific language. When you press it, it will type that letter and not \`, if you don't specify an U.S. input source, or any other layout that might have that key as \`. I just said U.S. as I know that works for sure. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Ah I thought English keyboard meant keyboard used in England

Comment: It could mean british keyboard as well, it seems you have the \` by default. :)

Answer (score 22):

*Disclaimer: This info is for English keyboards. If you're using a keyboard for a different language, look for the keys on your keyboard that match the photos.  Pictures of Apple's keyboards for various languages can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794).*

This question was answered 5 years ago, but pictures may be helpful for viewers coming upon it now.

**To make a backtick on the US English keyboard - Use the key just to the left of the 1 key**

[image: Backtick key]

**To make a backtick on the British or International English keyboard - Use the key just to the right of the left shift key**

[image: Backtick key Brit and Intl]

Comment: Only on a US keyboard - also note that the other answers already covered this.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was referring to a US keyboard, I'll update it to clarify. I was hoping the photos would help.

I added my answer since the majority of the other answers were incorrect in suggesting that the single quote key was a backtick as requested by the OP. Hope It helps someone :)

Answer (score 14):

If you have a *TURKISH* keyboard, and using *Turkish - QWERTY PC*, in order to type **´**, you need press **ALT + Ş**.

Gizem's comment:
In fact for backtick (`) TURKISH keyboard, you should press ALT and comma like this: (ALT,)

Comment: what about Turkish-F ?

Answer (score 5):

Search and use that key on a french keyboard :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On an US keyboard, it is right next to Shift.

Comment: he means ` not ' ` is next to 1 on a US keyboard under the ~

Answer (score 2):

You may find the backtick (`) character on the *Belgian* (BE) version of the Apple Macbook at the same place as the French (FR) layout - ref. Sébastien Gicquel.

[image: FR/BE keyboard layout MacBook]

Apparantly both BE and FR layouts of MacBooks keyboards are the same. Here's a list of MacBooks international layouts: https://keyshorts.com/blogs/blog/37615873-how-to-identify-macbook-keyboard-localization#belgian by Sebastian Kończak.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with non-English keyboard as well. Turns out it is rather easy to customize PressAndHold feature introduced in Lion. Here's how i did it: http://prii.it/blog/customize-press-and-hold-in-os-x-for-your-own-good

Now i have quick access to all symbols that are needed but missing on keyboard.

Comment: link does not work

Answer (score 0):

On **Danish** keyboard with **US layout**, press the `><` key for back tick.
Use the same key with shift modifier to get tilde symbol `~`.

[image]

It's a bit confusing at first, but I start to like the cmd+` shortcut (changing to another window of the same app) being so easy to reach.

And on a US keyboard with a Danish layout, press + and then space to get back tick.

Answer (score 0):

For a **Russian** keyboard I do recommend checking out this layout - https://ilyabirman.ru/typography-layout/

A lot of special symbols are available there.

The backtick is available through [Option] + [§] (In the top left corner if you follow the link above)

Comment: Аre Apple's Russian keyboards missing the backtick?

Answer (score -3):

Backtick is on the left of "1" keyboard button.

Comment: This is true only the the kind of keyboard sold in the US.  The person posting the question confirmed 4 years ago that on his keyboard it is next to Shift, which is the case for the kind of International English keyboard sold sold in most other countries.